# How to extract website title into row?

Tags: google-sheets

How to extract title (or other meta descriptions) of the website into row using Google Docs?

E.g. www.google.com

Comment: Why don't you give us an example to work with?

Comment: Any example would be good, posted www.google.com as example.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use built-in [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342) function which imports data from a table or list within an HTML page.

Here is the example:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.google.com","//title")
```

Some examples with similar meta tags:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.google.com","//meta[@name='description']/@content")
=IMPORTXML("http://www.google.com","//meta[@name='keywords']/@content")
```

Comment: Didn't know you could use `IMPORTXML` to fetch HTML tag soup. Interesting!