# How to get the +1's of a website?

Tags: google-sheets, google-plus-1

I've a spreadsheet with a lot of contact information. In order to sort the data, I want to rank them according to the +1's given on their website.

Is it possible to get the +1 count of a website using Google Spreadsheet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes that's possible !! See the below-mentioned formula to do just that.

### Formula

```
A2 = HYPERLINK("http://www.jacobjantuinstra.nl")

=IMPORTXML(
   "https://plusone.google.com/u/0/_/+1/fastbutton?&count=true&url=" & A2, // URL
   "//div[@id='aggregateCount']" // xpath_query  
 )

copy / paste
=IMPORTXML("https://plusone.google.com/u/0/_/+1/fastbutton?count=true&url="&A2,"//div[@id='aggregateCount']")
```

### Explained

The `URL` that is being fed as a first argument for the `IMPORTXML` formula, is constructed to contain the *plusone* URL that Google uses to perform +1 counts. The second argument is looking for a specific *div*, having an *id* equal to *aggregateCount*. All is possible when a website has a button, enabled for Google+.

### Screenshots

*hyperlinks*
[image]

*counts*
[image]

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[How to get the +1's of a website?](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheets/d/11-eBo8tpAQImoOErd6hrcr1-mwXEsET6DJ_o0mVfMDE/edit?usp=sharing)**
See **[this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/67539/29140)** post, here on Web Applications, on another usage of retrieving website info.

### H/T

- [Bruce McPherson](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+BruceMcpherson/posts), [Extract the plus one counts from a page - Desktop Liberation](https://plus.google.com/112066118406610145134/posts/HrvFqVEvj3S)