# How to extract IP address of the host into a row?

Tags: google-sheets, ip-addresses

It seems it's possible to [extract website title into a row](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/67538/how-to-extract-website-title-into-row), but how to extract IP address of the host into a row?

So for given any hostname (e.g. `webapps.stackexchange.com`) it should return IP address (e.g. `198.252.206.16`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably it's only possible by using some 3rd party web services which return IP addresses in HTML/XML format, so you can parse it via [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342).

In the example:

```
=importxml("http://xml.utrace.de/?query=webapps.stackexchange.com","//ip")
```

would return `198.252.206.16`.

Here is an example with a dynamic row as an input (e.g. A1):

```
=importxml("http://xml.utrace.de/?query=" & A1,"//ip")
```

Comment: +1; You don't have to use the CONCATENATE to build the query. This works as well: `=importxml("http://xml.utrace.de/?query="&"webapps.stackexchange.com","//ip")`

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra: Thanks, you've right. It was left over when I was testing it with dynamic rows as an input. I've updated with the version without it.

Comment: See: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/68989/29140

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra: Thanks, that was useful. Didn't know about `&` operator:)

Answer (score 3):

I found this works quite well with the following provider:

```
=importxml("http://freegeoip.net/xml/webapps.stackexchange.com", "//IP")
```

or dynamically:

```
=importxml("http://freegeoip.net/xml/" & A1,"//IP")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(IMPORTDATA("http://xml.utrace.de/?query="&A20), 
 "where Col1 contains 'ip'"), "<ip>|</ip>", "")
```

[image: 0]

```
=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://tools.keycdn.com/geo?host="&A20, "table", 1), 1, 2)
```

[image: 0]